# Navigation record searches specified with a missing keys or terms or both

Tags: endeca

error=Navigation record searches specified with a missing keys or terms or both

How to solve the above Oracle Endeca query error ?

Comment: Note : we are passing all required parameters but still getting above error,(N=2+1288888&Nrc=id+100000+exposed+false+dynrank+default+dyncount+default+dynorder+default&Ntk=all&Ntt=&Ntx=&Nty=1)

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming as Ntt and Ntx parameters are having the blank value.Since this is navigation query than no need to pass these parameters, NTK, Ntt and Ntx.

I tried at my end and looks like query passed to MDEX engine is not parsed properly and gives Failed to Parse URL

I hope this helps.

Thanks,
Ajay Agrawal